# Show line author in Eclipse with Perforce

Tags: java, perforce

I know this can be done in Eclipse with Subversion and Git going to Team->Show Annotation. Unfortunately, I can't see this option in the Team menu of Perforce. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do it within Eclipse, but you can certainly run 'p4 annotate' from the command line. And, if you also happen to have P4V installed, check out 'Time Lapse View'; it's a GREAT tool!

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I knew it could be done from P4V, but I was wondering whether I could do it from Eclipse as well. It is indeed in the Time Lapse view, which is also accessible from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Under Team->Time Lapse, there is a little icon of a man. Clicking on it will show who the author is.